# How to resolve 'Property 'foo' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor' when using @Input decorator?

Tags: angular, typescript

How would I correctly initialize a property that has an `@Input` decorator without removing strict typing?

Code below is what showing this warning

```
@Input
foo: FormGroup;
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is no way to define a decorator such that Typescript will know it will perform field initialization. The only option is to add a definite assignment modifier to the field:

```
@Input
foo!: FormGroup;
```

This will disable the check for this field alone. You can read more about this assertion [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/20166)

Answer (score 2):

Props need to have an exclamation mark appended, i.e. **`foo!: FormGroup.`**

Related **[Issue](https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-property-decorator/issues/81)**

Answer (score 1):

You can make the property optional, with "**?**".

```
@Input
foo?: FormGroup;
```

In addition, you can make the **input** required in the selector component

```
selector: 'app-name[foo]'
```

So that the component is selected only if it has foo input bound.